# Return 405 Method Not allowed from Asp.Net Core Webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

In the below API controller , How to return 405 Method Not allowed if POST or PUT is called on the API. Currently it is returning 404 not found .

```
[HttpGet]        
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Customer>> Get()
        {
            string query = "select* from Customers;";
            try
            {
                List<Customer> collection = GetCustomers(query);
                return Ok(collection);
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

Comment: you have a `[HttpGet]` attribute. .net core will do the 405 automatically.

Comment: what happens if you try calling the endpoint now with Post or Put? I believe it gives 405

Comment: It is returning 404 Not Found

Comment: where is `GetCustomers` defined?

Comment: Then your route is wrong. i.e. it actually *is* a 404. If you were hitting that actual action with anything other than GET, then you'd get a 405.

Comment: The API "https://localhost:5001/api/Customer" is working fine with GET . But the same API when called with POST . i am getting 404 rather than 405

Answer (score 3):

This issue is discussed in this thread:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/388